# Loop has a do but program says it doesn't

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have a simple yet infuriating question about a piece of code I am writing. For whatever reason, it insists I do no have a Do for my loop despite the do clearly being at the top. Perhaps I've done something while writing my If statements but I do not believe so. If you could look at it and help me out that would be great. Most of the code is a bunch of If, Then, GoTo statement so feel free to skim it.

```
 Do While Cells(i, "B").Value <> ""

'X Block
If Cells(i, "B").Value = "U" Then
        GoTo U1:
            ElseIf Cells(i, "B").Value = "C" Then
                GoTo C1:
                    ElseIf Cells(i, "B").Value = "A" Then
                        GoTo A1:
                            ElseIf Cells(i, "B").Value = "G" Then
                                GoTo G1:
End If

'UX Block
U1: If Cells(i + 1, "B").Value = "U" Then
    GoTo UU2:
        ElseIf Cells(i + 1, "B").Value = "C" Then
            GoTo UC2:
                ElseIf Cells(i + 1, "B").Value = "A" Then
                    GoTo UA2:
                        ElseIf Cells(i + 1, "B").Value = "G" Then
                            GoTo UG2:
End If

'UUX Block
 UU2: If Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "U" Or Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "C" Then
    Cells(a, "C").Value = "Phe"
        ElseIf Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "A" Or Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "G" Then
            Cells(a, "C").Value = "Leu"
End If
GoTo EndOfAcids:

'UCX Block
UC2: Cells(a, "C").Value = "Ser"
GoTo EndOfAcids:

'UAX Block
UA2: If Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "U" Or Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "C" Then
     Cells(a, "C").Value = "Tyr"
        ElseIf Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "A" Or Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "G" Then
            Cells(a, "C").Value = "Stop Codon"
End If
GoTo EndOfAcids:

'UGX Block
UG2: If Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "U" Or Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "C" Then
    Cells(a, "C").Value = "Cys"
        ElseIf Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "A" Then
            Cells(a, "C").Value = "Stop Codon"
                ElseIf Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "G" Then
                    Cells(a, "C").Value = "Trp"
End If
GoTo EndOfAcids:

'CX Block
C1: If Cells(i + 1, "B").Value = "U" Then
    GoTo CU2:
        ElseIf Cells(i + 1, "B").Value = "C" Then
            GoTo CC2:
                ElseIf Cells(i + 1, "B").Value = "A" Then
                    GoTo CA2:
                        ElseIf Cells(i + 1, "B").Value = "G" Then
                            GoTo CG2:
End If

'CUX Block
CU2: Cells(a, "C").Value = "Leu"
GoTo EndOfAcids:

'CCX Block
CC2: Cells(a, "C").Value = "Pro"
GoTo EndOfAcids:

'CAX Block
CA2: If Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "U" Or Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "C" Then
    Cells(a, "C").Value = "His"
         ElseIf Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "A" Or Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "G" Then
            Cells(a, "C").Value = "Gln"
End If
GoTo EndOfAcids:

'CGX Block
CG2: Cells(a, "C").Value = "Arg"
GoTo EndOfAcids:

'AX Block
A1: If Cells(i + 1, "B").Value = "U" Then
    GoTo AU2:
        ElseIf Cells(i + 1, "B").Value = "C" Then
            GoTo AC2:
                ElseIf Cells(i + 1, "B").Value = "A" Then
                    GoTo AA2:
                        ElseIf Cells(i + 1, "B").Value = "G" Then
                            GoTo AG2:
End If

'AUX Block
AU2: If Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "U" Or Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "C" Or Cells(i + 2).Value = "A" Then
    Cells(a, "C").Value = "Ile"
        ElseIf Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "G" Then
            Cells(a, "C").Value = "Met"
End If
GoTo EndOfAcids:

'ACX Block
AC2: Cells(a, "C").Value = "Thr"
GoTo EndOfAcids:

'AAX Block
AA2: If Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "U" Or Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "C" Then
    Cells(a, "C").Value = "Asn"
         ElseIf Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "A" Or Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "G" Then
            Cells(a, "C").Value = "Lys"
End If
 GoTo EndOfAcids:

'AGX Block
AG2: If Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "U" Or Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "C" Then
    Cells(a, "C").Value = "Ser"
         ElseIf Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "A" Or Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "G" Then
            Cells(a, "C").Value = "Arg"
End If
GoTo EndOfAcids:

'GX Block
G1: If Cells(i + 1, "B").Value = "U" Then
    GoTo GU2:
    ElseIf Cells(i + 1, "B").Value = "C" Then
        GoTo GC2:
        ElseIf Cells(i + 1, "B").Value = "A" Then
            GoTo GA2:
                ElseIf Cells(i + 1, "B").Value = "G" Then
                    GoTo GG2:
End If

'GUX Block
GU2: Cells(a, "C").Value = "Val"
GoTo EndOfAcids:

'GCX Block
 GC2: Cells(a, "C").Value = "Ala"
 GoTo EndOfAcids:

'GAX Block
GA2:  If Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "U" Or Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "C" Then
    Cells(a, "C").Value = "Asp"
        ElseIf Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "A" Or Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "G" Then
            Cells(a, "C").Value = "Glu"
GoTo EndOfAcids:

'GGX Block
GG2: Cells(a, "C").Value = "Gly"
GoTo EndOfAcids:

EndOfAcids:

i = i + 3
a = a + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

So the do is at the top of the code but when I run it the program says there is no do. Not sure why. Any help would be appreciated. There is slightly more code so I will post the entirety below but the problem loop is what is posted above.

```
Option Explicit

Sub RNATrascription()
Dim i As Long
Dim a As Long


i = 2
a = 2
Do While Cells(i, "A").Value <> ""
If Cells(i, "A").Value = "A" Or Cells(i, "A").Value = "a" Then
    Cells(i, "B").Value = "U"
        ElseIf Cells(i, "A").Value = "T" Or Cells(i, "A").Value = "t" Then
            Cells(i, "B").Value = "A"
                ElseIf Cells(i, "A") = "G" Or Cells(i, "A").Value = "g" Then
                    Cells(i, "B") = "C"
                        ElseIf Cells(i, "A") = "C" Or Cells(i, "A").Value = "c" Then
                            Cells(i, "B") = "G"
                                ElseIf Cells(i, "A") <> "A" Or Cells(i, "A") <> "a" Or Cells(i, "A") <> "T" Or Cells(i, "A") <> "t" Or Cells(i, "A") <> "G" Or Cells(i, "A") <> "g" Or Cells(i, "A") <> "C" Or Cells(i, "A") <> "c" Then
                                    MsgBox "You have mis typed your DNA sequence"
End If
i = i + 1

Loop

Do While Cells(i, "B").Value <> ""

'X Block
If Cells(i, "B").Value = "U" Then
        GoTo U1:
            ElseIf Cells(i, "B").Value = "C" Then
                GoTo C1:
                    ElseIf Cells(i, "B").Value = "A" Then
                        GoTo A1:
                            ElseIf Cells(i, "B").Value = "G" Then
                                GoTo G1:
End If

'UX Block
U1: If Cells(i + 1, "B").Value = "U" Then
    GoTo UU2:
        ElseIf Cells(i + 1, "B").Value = "C" Then
            GoTo UC2:
                ElseIf Cells(i + 1, "B").Value = "A" Then
                    GoTo UA2:
                        ElseIf Cells(i + 1, "B").Value = "G" Then
                            GoTo UG2:
End If

'UUX Block
 UU2: If Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "U" Or Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "C" Then
    Cells(a, "C").Value = "Phe"
        ElseIf Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "A" Or Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "G" Then
            Cells(a, "C").Value = "Leu"
End If
GoTo EndOfAcids:

'UCX Block
UC2: Cells(a, "C").Value = "Ser"
GoTo EndOfAcids:

'UAX Block
UA2: If Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "U" Or Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "C" Then
     Cells(a, "C").Value = "Tyr"
        ElseIf Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "A" Or Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "G" Then
            Cells(a, "C").Value = "Stop Codon"
End If
GoTo EndOfAcids:

'UGX Block
UG2: If Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "U" Or Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "C" Then
    Cells(a, "C").Value = "Cys"
        ElseIf Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "A" Then
            Cells(a, "C").Value = "Stop Codon"
                ElseIf Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "G" Then
                    Cells(a, "C").Value = "Trp"
End If
GoTo EndOfAcids:

'CX Block
C1: If Cells(i + 1, "B").Value = "U" Then
    GoTo CU2:
        ElseIf Cells(i + 1, "B").Value = "C" Then
            GoTo CC2:
                ElseIf Cells(i + 1, "B").Value = "A" Then
                    GoTo CA2:
                        ElseIf Cells(i + 1, "B").Value = "G" Then
                            GoTo CG2:
End If

'CUX Block
CU2: Cells(a, "C").Value = "Leu"
GoTo EndOfAcids:

'CCX Block
CC2: Cells(a, "C").Value = "Pro"
GoTo EndOfAcids:

'CAX Block
CA2: If Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "U" Or Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "C" Then
    Cells(a, "C").Value = "His"
         ElseIf Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "A" Or Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "G" Then
            Cells(a, "C").Value = "Gln"
End If
GoTo EndOfAcids:

'CGX Block
CG2: Cells(a, "C").Value = "Arg"
GoTo EndOfAcids:

'AX Block
A1: If Cells(i + 1, "B").Value = "U" Then
    GoTo AU2:
        ElseIf Cells(i + 1, "B").Value = "C" Then
            GoTo AC2:
                ElseIf Cells(i + 1, "B").Value = "A" Then
                    GoTo AA2:
                        ElseIf Cells(i + 1, "B").Value = "G" Then
                            GoTo AG2:
End If

'AUX Block
AU2: If Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "U" Or Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "C" Or Cells(i + 2).Value = "A" Then
    Cells(a, "C").Value = "Ile"
        ElseIf Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "G" Then
            Cells(a, "C").Value = "Met"
End If
GoTo EndOfAcids:

'ACX Block
AC2: Cells(a, "C").Value = "Thr"
GoTo EndOfAcids:

'AAX Block
AA2: If Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "U" Or Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "C" Then
    Cells(a, "C").Value = "Asn"
         ElseIf Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "A" Or Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "G" Then
            Cells(a, "C").Value = "Lys"
End If
 GoTo EndOfAcids:

'AGX Block
AG2: If Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "U" Or Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "C" Then
    Cells(a, "C").Value = "Ser"
         ElseIf Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "A" Or Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "G" Then
            Cells(a, "C").Value = "Arg"
End If
GoTo EndOfAcids:

'GX Block
G1: If Cells(i + 1, "B").Value = "U" Then
    GoTo GU2:
    ElseIf Cells(i + 1, "B").Value = "C" Then
        GoTo GC2:
        ElseIf Cells(i + 1, "B").Value = "A" Then
            GoTo GA2:
                ElseIf Cells(i + 1, "B").Value = "G" Then
                    GoTo GG2:
End If

'GUX Block
GU2: Cells(a, "C").Value = "Val"
GoTo EndOfAcids:

'GCX Block
 GC2: Cells(a, "C").Value = "Ala"
 GoTo EndOfAcids:

'GAX Block
GA2:  If Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "U" Or Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "C" Then
    Cells(a, "C").Value = "Asp"
        ElseIf Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "A" Or Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "G" Then
            Cells(a, "C").Value = "Glu"
GoTo EndOfAcids:

'GGX Block
GG2: Cells(a, "C").Value = "Gly"
GoTo EndOfAcids:

EndOfAcids:

i = i + 3
a = a + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: please reformat your code properly ... it is horrible to look at

Comment: I will bet that you have an IF without an End if some where in the code.  BTW using GoTo is probably the most confusing method to write code.  Also none of you Range Object have a parent attached, this could become problematic.

Comment: Look at your GA2 block.  It is missing the `End If`

Comment: Desperately need to use a lookup table instead of all this code.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_code#RNA_codon_table

Comment: It's incredible that out of the five people who answered, only one actually answered the question. Exactly how I remember it.

Comment: @Sooner2 You ever think that they see that it was and were trying to point you in a direction that would help you in the future?.....Tim, Mat and Scott are very Knowledgeable in this arena and all suggestions would help you.

Comment: You forgot to mention snarky comments from posters unhappy that all respondents weren't keen to trawl through a long block of difficult-to-read code: that happens too.

Comment: @Sooner2...this is a classic [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You show us long block of code (your attempted Y solution) without telling us the scenario (the X problem). Very frustrating for answerers. Back up and tell us the full situation (i.e., data input, desired output). I can guarantee you do not need all these `If` or `Goto` blocks.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub RNATrascription()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim a As Long
    Dim dat As String

    i = 2

    Do While Cells(i, "A").Value <> ""
        Select Case LCase(Cells(i, "A").Value)
            Case "a": dat = "U"
            Case "t": dat = "A"
            Case "g": dat = "C"
            Case "c": dat = "G"
            Case Else
                MsgBox "You have mis typed your DNA sequence"
                End
        End Select

        Cells(i, "B") = dat

        i = i + 1
    Loop

    i = 2
    a = 2

    Dim cc2 As String
    Dim cc3 As String

    Do While Cells(i, "B").Value <> ""

        cc2 = Cells(i, "B") & Cells(i + 1, "B")
        cc3 = cc2 & Cells(i + 2, "B")

        dat = ""

        Select Case cc2
            Case "uc": dat = "Ser"
            Case "cu": dat = "Leu"
            Case "cc": dat = "Pro"
            Case "ac": dat = "Thr"
            Case "gu": dat = "Val"
            Case "gc": dat = "Ala"
        End Select

        If dat = "" Then
            Select Case cc3
                Case "uuu", "uuc": dat = "Phe"
                Case "uua", "uug": dat = "Ley"
                Case "uau", "uac": dat = "Tyr"
                Case "uaa", "uag", "uga": dat = "Stop Codon"
                Case "ugu", "ugc": dat = "Sys"
                Case "ugg": dat = "Trp"
                Case "cau": dat = "His"
                Case "caa": dat = "Gln"
                Case "cgc": dat = "Arg"
                Case "auu", "aua": dat = "Ile"
                Case "aug": dat = "Met"
                Case "aau", "agu", "agc": dat = "Asn"
                Case "aaa", "aga", "agg": dat = "Lys"
                Case "gau", "gac": dat = "Asp"
                Case "gaa", "gag": dat = "Glu"
                Case Else: dat = "ERROR"
            End Select
        End If

        Cells(a, "C").Value = dat

        i = i + 3
        a = a + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: I was unaware of the ability to use cases like this. Seems like a much more concise way of saying the same thing. I will keep this in mind for future works. Thanks for the alternative idea.

Answer (score 0):

your code should have been formatted something like this .... if you did that in the first place, you may have noticed that there is no `end if` in the GAX block

```
Option Explicit

Sub RNATrascription()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim a As Long

    i = 2
    a = 2
    Do While Cells(i, "A").Value <> ""

        If Cells(i, "A").Value = "A" Or Cells(i, "A").Value = "a" Then
            Cells(i, "B").Value = "U"
        ElseIf Cells(i, "A").Value = "T" Or Cells(i, "A").Value = "t" Then
            Cells(i, "B").Value = "A"
        ElseIf Cells(i, "A") = "G" Or Cells(i, "A").Value = "g" Then
            Cells(i, "B") = "C"
        ElseIf Cells(i, "A") = "C" Or Cells(i, "A").Value = "c" Then
            Cells(i, "B") = "G"
        ElseIf Cells(i, "A") <> "A" Or Cells(i, "A") <> "a" Or Cells(i, "A") <> "T" Or Cells(i, "A") <> "t" Or Cells(i, "A") <> "G" Or Cells(i, "A") <> "g" Or Cells(i, "A") <> "C" Or Cells(i, "A") <> "c" Then
            MsgBox "You have mis typed your DNA sequence"
        End If
        i = i + 1

    Loop

    Do While Cells(i, "B").Value <> ""

        'X Block
        If Cells(i, "B").Value = "U" Then
            GoTo U1:
        ElseIf Cells(i, "B").Value = "C" Then
            GoTo C1:
        ElseIf Cells(i, "B").Value = "A" Then
            GoTo A1:
        ElseIf Cells(i, "B").Value = "G" Then
            GoTo G1:
        End If

        'UX Block
U1:
        If Cells(i + 1, "B").Value = "U" Then
            GoTo UU2:
        ElseIf Cells(i + 1, "B").Value = "C" Then
            GoTo UC2:
        ElseIf Cells(i + 1, "B").Value = "A" Then
            GoTo UA2:
        ElseIf Cells(i + 1, "B").Value = "G" Then
            GoTo UG2:
        End If

        'UUX Block
UU2:
        If Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "U" Or Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "C" Then
            Cells(a, "C").Value = "Phe"
        ElseIf Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "A" Or Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "G" Then
            Cells(a, "C").Value = "Leu"
        End If
        GoTo EndOfAcids:

        'UCX Block
UC2:
        Cells(a, "C").Value = "Ser"
        GoTo EndOfAcids:

        'UAX Block
UA2:
        If Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "U" Or Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "C" Then
            Cells(a, "C").Value = "Tyr"
        ElseIf Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "A" Or Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "G" Then
            Cells(a, "C").Value = "Stop Codon"
        End If
        GoTo EndOfAcids:

        'UGX Block
UG2:
        If Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "U" Or Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "C" Then
            Cells(a, "C").Value = "Cys"
        ElseIf Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "A" Then
            Cells(a, "C").Value = "Stop Codon"
        ElseIf Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "G" Then
            Cells(a, "C").Value = "Trp"
        End If
        GoTo EndOfAcids:

        'CX Block
C1:
        If Cells(i + 1, "B").Value = "U" Then
            GoTo CU2:
        ElseIf Cells(i + 1, "B").Value = "C" Then
            GoTo CC2:
        ElseIf Cells(i + 1, "B").Value = "A" Then
            GoTo CA2:
        ElseIf Cells(i + 1, "B").Value = "G" Then
            GoTo CG2:
        End If

        'CUX Block
CU2:
        Cells(a, "C").Value = "Leu"
        GoTo EndOfAcids:

        'CCX Block
CC2:
        Cells(a, "C").Value = "Pro"
        GoTo EndOfAcids:

        'CAX Block
CA2:
        If Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "U" Or Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "C" Then
            Cells(a, "C").Value = "His"
        ElseIf Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "A" Or Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "G" Then
            Cells(a, "C").Value = "Gln"
        End If
        GoTo EndOfAcids:

        'CGX Block
CG2:
        Cells(a, "C").Value = "Arg"
        GoTo EndOfAcids:

        'AX Block
A1:
        If Cells(i + 1, "B").Value = "U" Then
            GoTo AU2:
        ElseIf Cells(i + 1, "B").Value = "C" Then
            GoTo AC2:
        ElseIf Cells(i + 1, "B").Value = "A" Then
            GoTo AA2:
        ElseIf Cells(i + 1, "B").Value = "G" Then
            GoTo AG2:
        End If

        'AUX Block
AU2:
        If Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "U" Or Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "C" Or Cells(i + 2).Value = "A" Then
            Cells(a, "C").Value = "Ile"
        ElseIf Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "G" Then
            Cells(a, "C").Value = "Met"
        End If
        GoTo EndOfAcids:

        'ACX Block
AC2:
        Cells(a, "C").Value = "Thr"
        GoTo EndOfAcids:

        'AAX Block
AA2:
        If Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "U" Or Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "C" Then
            Cells(a, "C").Value = "Asn"
        ElseIf Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "A" Or Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "G" Then
            Cells(a, "C").Value = "Lys"
        End If
        GoTo EndOfAcids:

        'AGX Block
AG2:
        If Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "U" Or Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "C" Then
            Cells(a, "C").Value = "Ser"
        ElseIf Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "A" Or Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "G" Then
            Cells(a, "C").Value = "Arg"
        End If
        GoTo EndOfAcids:

        'GX Block
G1:
        If Cells(i + 1, "B").Value = "U" Then
            GoTo GU2:
        ElseIf Cells(i + 1, "B").Value = "C" Then
            GoTo GC2:
        ElseIf Cells(i + 1, "B").Value = "A" Then
            GoTo GA2:
        ElseIf Cells(i + 1, "B").Value = "G" Then
            GoTo GG2:
        End If

        'GUX Block
GU2: 
        Cells(a, "C").Value = "Val"
        GoTo EndOfAcids:

        'GCX Block
GC2:
        Cells(a, "C").Value = "Ala"
        GoTo EndOfAcids:

        'GAX Block
GA2:
        If Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "U" Or Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "C" Then
            Cells(a, "C").Value = "Asp"
        ElseIf Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "A" Or Cells(i + 2, "B").Value = "G" Then
            Cells(a, "C").Value = "Glu"
        GoTo EndOfAcids:

        'GGX Block
GG2:
        Cells(a, "C").Value = "Gly"
        GoTo EndOfAcids:

EndOfAcids:

        i = i + 3
        a = a + 1

    Loop

End Sub
```